# Rails best_in_place gem while clicking on the label name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I am using the best in place gem - which is great.
Only thing is that I want the user to be able to click not just the best in place element in order to edit it, but also the label. 
Lets say I have this best in place element:

```
<b>Open Hours</b>
<%= best_in_place @provider, :open_hours, :type => :select, :collection => Provider::PROVIDERS_HOURS %>
```

I want to be able to click the Open Hours in order to open the edit element. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For single instance of a class you can simply

```
<b id='edit-open-hours'>Open Hours</b>
<%= best_in_place @provider, :open_hours, type: :select, collection: Provider::PROVIDERS_HOURS, activator: '#edit-open-hours' %>
```

If you want to do this with a list view you will need to make each id-identifier unique with an ID

```
<b id='edit-<%= @provider.id %>'>Open Hours</b>
<%= best_in_place @provider, :open_hours, type: :select, collection: Provider::PROVIDERS_HOURS, activator: '#edit-' + @provider.id.to_s %>
```

Comment: Your answer really did the trick. Thanks a lot man!  I have made a small update to your answer with the missing '#' .  activator: '#edit-' + @provider.id.to_s

Answer (score 3):

This was very helpful, but a small correction: you have to prefix the activator DOM element with the relevant symbol (# for id, . for class).

So the second example would be

```
<%= best_in_place @provider, :open_hours, type: :select, collection: Provider::PROVIDERS_HOURS, activator: '#edit-' + @provider.id.to_s %>
```